# php email script not working correctly

Tags: email, php

I have a form on my website:

```
 <form name="contact" action="contact.php" method="post">
      <label for="name">Name:</label><br/><input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br/>
      <label for="email">Email:</label><br/><input type="text" name="email" id="email"><br/>
      <label for="comment">Question:</label><br/><textarea name="comment" id="comment"></textarea><br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Send" id="submit">
      </form>
```

This is the script it submits the data to:

```
    <?php
header("Refresh: 3;url=http://www.xyz.com/");

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    $email_to = "xxxx@gmail.com";
    $email_subject = "Enquiry";


    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comment'])){
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }

    $name = $_POST['name']; // required
    $email = $_POST['email']; // required
    $comment = $_POST['comment']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(strlen($comment) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comment: ".clean_string($comment)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

<!-- include your own success html here -->

Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.


<?php
}
?>
```

For some reason the script outputs that the message was sent successfully but when I check my inbox there is no new emails. I don't know what is going on, can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you checked your mail server logs to see what happens? Why are you suppressing the output from `mail()`? Is there anything in your spam folder?

Comment: Out of curiosity... Why do you think you need to strip out stuff like "to:" from the message body?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario to be honest I am not the author of this script. I merely have taken it and adapted it to suit my needs with the permission of the original author of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mail function has errors turned off

```
 @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
```

remove `@` from this and add simple if

```
if(mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers))
{
  echo 'mail was sent'; //success message here
}
else
{
  echo 'there were errors during sending mail'; //error message there
}
```

When you find out what errors occur then you can remove them. It can be problem with configuration of SMTP server.

You can set some settings affecting mail() function in php.ini

[Read more here.](http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php)

Moreover, this `Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.` message is shown always it doesn't check if something is wrong it is just shown.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that there, thank you for your help. I did as you suggested and I am echoing "Mail was sent" so perhaps I just need to be patient and the email will eventually show up in my inbox...

Comment: BTW why do you need to refresh the page every 3 s?

Comment: I put that in because I wanted to redirect the user to the homepage after 3 seconds. I found an answer to question on this site that suggested this was the way to go about doing that